# error: Too few arguments to function Campaign::camp_detls(), 0 passed exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, runtime-error, codeigniter-3

i have a table name **tbl_campaign_detail** in which **blogger_ID** and **Campaign_id**  are added as a **foreign key** with some other fields..

i want to delete record from this table.. when i perform delete, it deleted the record but also give an error,

**error:**

> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Campaign::camp_detls(), 0 passed in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\bms\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\bms\application\controllers\Campaign.php
>
> Line Number: 35

it works perfectly but also shows this error...

Here is my model:

```
public function camp_detl_delete($did){

    $this->db->where('detail_id', $did);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_campaign_detail');
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function camp_detl_delete($id){
    $result = $this->cm->camp_detl_delete($id);
    if($result){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Record deleted successfully');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Faill to delete record');
    }
    redirect(base_url('campaign/camp_detls/')); //this should be directed to particular id of camp_detls
}
```

And view:

```
$did = $cmp->detail_id;
<a href="<?php echo base_url('campaign/camp_detl_delete/' .$did); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>
```

but where it shows error mentioned in controller line 35 is:

```
function camp_detls($id){
    $data['camps'] = $this->cm->camp_detailByID($id);
    $data['campaign'] = $this->cm->getCampaignsById($id);
    $data['blogger'] = $this->cm->getAllBloggers();
    $data['cat'] = $this->cm->getAllCategory();
    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    $this->load->view('campaign/campaign_detail', $data);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');
}
```

Kindly help, how can i remove this error ?
i just want it delete simply.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call camp_detls()? That is the method the error refers to.

Comment: i dont get it `//this should be directed to particular id of camp_detls` ... you say want to delete record with id 1, the record is now deleted, why do you want to go back to id 1? it isn't there anymore.

Comment: Thanks Bro... base_url('campaign/camp_detls/' . $id) this thing worked

Comment: Alex actually its an inner page... the outer page is also based on id.. so i want that i can delete record and shows the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Message: Too few arguments to function Campaign::camp_detls(), 0
>   passed (...)

This error means for you that to the function (`camp_detls()`) you defined and required `$id` as  argument was nothing passed.

I suppose the problem is in the line:

```
redirect(base_url('campaign/camp_detls/')); //this should be directed to particular id of camp_detls
```

as comment suggesting it, but look. Here you want to redirect to particular `camp_detls` but you do not provide `$id`.

Comment: I added refresh here like redirect(base_url('campaign/camp_detls/','refresh')); 
but now its dont shows the error and delete the record perfectly. but when i presses delete button it do nothing until i refresh the page...

Comment: simply: on pressing delete it deleted the record but still record shows on the page until i refresh the page...

Comment: Could you try to use `base_url('campaign/camp_detls/' . $id)` ?